# How to achieve video.js control-bar layout skin css sibling elements 2 siblings on top, 4 siblings on bottom left, the last siblings on bottom right

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, video.js

How can I achieve this layout given that all these div elements are siblings? My use case is for a video player control bar layout. All the control bar items are siblings and so I'm having some difficulty positioning the control bar items without being able to group some elements in divs to move around. I'm currently using video.js 7.x https://videojs.com/ attempting to build a custom skin layout.

[image: video player layout css]

```
<div class="video-control-bar>
  <div class="1"></div>
  <div class="2"></div>
  <div class="3"></div>
  <div class="4"></div>
  <div class="5"></div>
  <div class="6"></div>
  <div class="7"></div>
  <div class="8"></div>
  <div class="9"></div>
</div>
```

I'm able to achieve this so far with `flex-basis: 95%` on #1 and `flex-basis: 5%` on #2, but I can't seem to get #7, 8, 9 to appear at the end of the div.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For now, one solution is to set `flex: 1` to **#6**, which then pushes 6 out to as far as #6 container can grow.